# How to keep example action on navigation drawer open?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using the android navigation drawer template, but when I open the drawer the 'example action' button disappears. I want it to stay, but I don't know where the code that removes it is.

My example action button is called Refresh

http://s3.postimg.org/3zp3l1txf/Screenshot_2015_06_30_14_03_58.png

http://s17.postimg.org/lmmmcvybz/Screenshot_2015_06_30_14_04_01.png

Thanks

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
```

Comment: Look in your activity and find the code for the methods `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and post them here. These are most likely where the issues lie

Comment: @Joseph Roque The code will be the same as the template, but yes I will post it later on :)

Comment: Just post another comment @ me when you do, so I can see your edit and help you out :)

Comment: Is that the code from the Fragment or the Activity? In the Activity, there should be another method `onCreateOptionsMenu` which has an `if statement` that looks something like: `if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen())` (I'm not 100% sure what the exact if is) and if you get rid of the surrounding if statement, it should continue to show your action button constantly.

Comment: @JosephRoque         if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;

Comment: @JosephRoque Can I not just show the button without showing everything?

Comment: @JosephRoque Ok, what I did is just after the end of the if statement, I put the same menu inflate command :)

Comment: @JosephRoque How can I change what that button does when it is pressed? I really dislike the circle that appears behind it, how can I change it to something else? One half of the circle that appears is squared off, sort of, so if I can't change hat I I'll have to change the button

Comment: Yeah, what those comments mean is basically "If the navigation drawer is open, we're only going to show the user the 'navigation options' and when its closed, they can see the actual options".  So you can get rid of the if statement altogether and only have that menu inflate command, because you want to show the same actions regardless of if the drawer is open or not.

Comment: As for the changing what the button does, look at the method `onOptionItemSelected`

Comment: @JosephRoque and the onOptionItemSelected method is for my refresh button? Or is it for a nav bar option?